# Sharepoint: Multiple refinement filters with and condition (Using rest API for Angular4)

Tags: angular, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I m using SharePoint rest api to retrieve data:

```
myURL/_api/search/query?rowlimit=500&trimduplicates=false+ .... +
refinementfilters=%27CountryCDH:("USA")%27,%27(ColorChoiceCDH:("Red"),ColorChoiceCDH:("Blue"))%27
```

Here is my requirement:
I do have three column which can have mixed search on data.

- Country ( It can be USA, UK, ..)
- Color ( it can be red/blue/green)
- Type ( S, M, L, XL)

How do I create refinement filter query out of it?

Currently getting the issue for building a query.

```
-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException
 The expression "'CountryCDH:("USA")','(ColorChoiceCDH:("Red"),ColorChoiceCDH:("Blue"))'" is not valid.
```

Thanks in advance. Help me to build query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general pattern for ANDs and ORs:

```
&refinementfilters='or(fileExtension:equals("docx"),fileExtension:equals("pptx"))'
```

Assuming you are using *refinable* properties, them maybe something like:

```
&refinementfilters='and(CountryCDH:equals("USA"),ColorChoiceCDH:equals("Red"),ColorChoiceCDH:equals("Blue"))'
```

Comment: If I wanted to check substring, how do I manage? instead of equals, can I check for substring since a user can have multiple color choices

Comment: See here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36328/change-search-refinement-from-equals-to-contains

Comment: If a wildcard (*) at the end is acceptable, see the answer here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5eb4cd2e-2edf-4ac5-807d-a968f0996e61/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-refinementfilters-containts-or-substrinof-operator